# Why do I need a common account in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Why do I need a common account in Oracle 12c? A common means a `CDB` account. When I create an account using enterprise manager express it's creating only common accounts. Could I create a non-common account there? A common user also appears in every container I ever switch/connect to. What's the purpose of this common account to access all those pluggable databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I need a common account in Oracle 12c?
>   What's the purpose of this common account to access all those pluggable databases?

You need a common account(common user) to perform administrative operations on CDB(container database) such as changing the state of a pluggable database, plugging and unplugging pluggable databases (PDBs) and so forth, which local user cannot do. Well, in fact, a local user can change state of pluggable database as well, but only PDB it connected to as sysdba or sysoper.

> Could I create a non-common account there(in CDB)?

No, non-common account(Local user) cannot be created in the root - can only be created and operate within a pluggable database(PDB) and wont have access(you cannot use it to log in to) CDB or other PDBs.

[Find out](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17633/cdblogic.htm#CIHIAJED) more
about commonality and [common and local users](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/network.121/e17607/users.htm#CIHDJEBC).

---

**Edit**

`CDB$ROOT` is root container. `PDB$SEED` is just a template needed to create a pluggable databases. You cannot create or modify objects in it. `PDBORCL` is a pluggable database, which you should use for your development.

Oracle will throw the `ORA-01033` error if you are trying to connect to a closed PDB as non sysdba user. Usually, PDBs database are not open by default, just mounted (unless your have automated that process by creating a trigger, for example, that will do it for you upon starting up CDB) and you need to explicitly open it while connecting as a common user (SYS or other common user that has the privilege to startup/alter pluggable database) and issue:

```
SQL> alter pluggable database <<name_of_PDB>> open;

or

SQL> startup pluggable database <<name_of_PDB>>
```

After that you should be able to connect to your PDB as common or local user. Of course they have to have appropriate privileges(`create session`) to be able to do so.

---

**Edit #2** Automating starting up of pluggable database(s) on startup of CDB using system event(`after startup on database`) trigger. Unfortunately there is no native way to startup PDs automatically.

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME                
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT            

SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED 
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO 
         3 NKRASNOV                       READ WRITE NO
```

This specific trigger opens one pluggable database. If you have more than one PDs and want to open them all, the alter statement can be modified as follows `ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL OPEN;`

```
SQL> create or replace trigger open_pdb
  2  after startup on database
  3  begin
  4    execute immediate 'alter pluggable database nkrasnov open';
  5  end;
  6  /

Trigger created.

SQL> shutdown

Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.

SQL> startup

ORACLE instance started.

Database mounted.
Database opened.

SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED  
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ---------- 
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO 
         3 NKRASNOV                       READ WRITE NO

SQL> conn hr/hr@nkrasnov_pdb
Connected.

SQL> spool off;
```

Comment: When I list all PDBs from services it shows CDB$ROOT as well as PDBORCL and PDB$SEED. Which of them I should use to develop web application? i was trying to create a tablespace for common and pdborcl user and objects in that tablespace when connecting as common and/or pdb user with service name. That worked, but today PDBORCL seems not working. I can't see it among PDBs in EM Express. So, I can't connect to it anymore with SQL Developer I've got ORA-01033. Restarting database didn't help, still can connect to CDB$ROOT. What's wrong I have made?

Comment: yes, I've tried `alter` or `startup` PDB but after reboot or CDB restart the PDB `OPEN_STATE` is rolled back to `MOUNTED`. I see the option of a trigger (could you provide example) to open read write PDB on startup CDB, thanks for your help. Any other option to automate it?

Comment: After the trigger SQL> shutdown immediate;
ORA-24324: service handle not initialized
ORA-24323: value not allowed
ORA-01090: shutdown in progress - connection is not permitted

Comment: @nikpon Try `shutdown abort`. Try completely restart the system. Check alert log, see what errors Oracle has put there.